# Why does the IDE error parsers represent the Size property of NativeInt as error?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I have recently started using the built-in helper classes for basic data types, makes them look like C#. The IDE has a really unusual behavior associated only with NativeInt and NativeUInt helpers, as such it interprets the Size property to be undefined.

Its a nuisance to see a line of errors which are actually not there, and then sniffing through them for the real errors. Other mistakes made by the IDE error parsers can almost always be mitigated with a successful compile but this one never goes away.

Does somebody know a solution to this aside from not using the property and switching back to SizeOf ()? A hack solution is also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable "Error Insight" in the IDE settings.  Seriously.  It never works right, reports false errors that are not real errors, etc. It gets its info from a separate source then the actual code, and easily gets out of sync.  Best to just not use it at all.